# How to paste columns in batches

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to paste multiple columns together using some separator but I want to combine the columns in groups of let's say 2.  For instance, I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
colnames(df) <- x
df$a <- c("man", "bear", "pig")
df$b <- c("chicken", "moose", "bear")
df$c <- c("fish", "dog", "bear")
df$d <- c("dog", "mouse", "moose")

df
#     a       b    c     d
#1  man chicken fish   dog
#2 bear   moose  dog mouse
#3  pig    bear bear moose
```

and I would like to combine columns `a + b` and `c + d`, respectively.  I can get it to work by pasting it together in steps as such:

```
df$combined1 <- paste(df$a, df$b, sep = " + ")
df$combined2 <- paste(df$c, df$d, sep = " + ")
```

but I would really like to adhere to the DRY principle for some cleaner code.  I tried doing it with `unite` as well but no luck.  Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the spirit of readability let's simplify your data creation code. Definitely don't need all those intermediate variables:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = c("man", "bear", "pig"),
    b = c("chicken", "moose", "bear"),
    c = c("fish", "dog", "bear"),
    d = c("dog", "mouse", "moose")
)
```

Now to the meat of your question. This is very general. First we define a list of columns to combine, and then we combine them, creating the names of the combined columns and combining them only by referencing the data and the combination list:

```
cols_to_combine = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))

for (comb in cols_to_combine) {
    df[[paste0("combined_", paste(comb, collapse = "_"))]] =
        do.call(paste, args = c(df[comb], sep = " + "))
}

df
#      a       b    c     d  combined_1_2 combined_3_4
# 1  man chicken fish   dog man + chicken   fish + dog
# 2 bear   moose  dog mouse  bear + moose  dog + mouse
# 3  pig    bear bear moose    pig + bear bear + moose
```